# Displaying d3 chart in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, d3.js

I was going through the library NVD3 and have found this as an example on the website:

```
d3.json('cumulativeLineData.json', function(data) {
  nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
                  .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                  .y(function(d) { return d[1]/100 }) //adjusting, 100% is 1.00, not 100 as it is in the data
                  .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
                  .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                  ;

     chart.xAxis
        .tickValues([1078030800000,1122782400000,1167541200000,1251691200000])
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
          });

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data)
        .call(chart);

    //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
  });
});
```

The image is something like this:
[image]

Check the live demo here:  http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html

The json file is here: [Json file for example](http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLineData.json)
Now I was willing to include such charts in the django example. So I went on checking the implementation of Django-NVD3. But I could not find anything related to it and the documentation written by author is not understood by me.

Please let me know how I can include d3 chart in the django frame in real time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django largely is backend framework for python. That means it creates responses to html requests. These responses are rendered using templates that contain the html code which is being created on the fly.

nvd3.js or d3.js for that matter live on the frontend, i.e. the user's browser. That means all nvd3.js html and javascript code (like the one you quote) go into the **Django template**.

To use nvd3.js you will have to **load** the d3.js and nvd3.js **javascript libraries** and corresponding **style sheets**. (On how to do this, see the respective documentations.) These elements need to go to a different place in the template (html where the chart is supposed to go, css into the header and javascript at the end of the body).

**django-nvd3** is a django app that is used to simplify the use of nvd3 on the front end. It is one option to work with Django and nvd3.js. It defines template tags that will include the required javascript code and style sheets in your template. The first tag `include_chart_jscss` will do exactly this and is supposed to be used in the `<head>` section of the tempalte. The second tag `load_chart`will generate the javascript you quoted actually creating the chart. The third tag (`include_container`) will insert the required html `div` elements (which you did not quote in the questions). By passing the latter tags the same name the browser knows on which div tag to apply the javascript code. It does not help to distribute the code bits over the template. Also, it does not generate the code. This is left to a different package `python-nvd3` which itself relies on a template engine (Jinja2) which likely is different from the one you use with Django. **In a nutshell: django-nvd3 solves the problem of generating javascript code for nvd3 charts but not the problem of how to distribute that code in django templates.**

I suggest [**Sekizai**](https://github.com/divio/django-sekizai) to better distribute code bits. It allows to split html, css and js bits of a page in separate blocks. Then you can use  simple includes to add a chart to your web page. In the included file you may surround the required css code by `{% addtoblock css %}` and the required 
javascript by `{% addtoblock js %}`. When using sekizai the base templates need to have these block ("js" and "css") defined, see the [Sekizai documentation](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Of course it is a matter of opinion, but I prefer using sekizai for distributing the nvd3.js code bits in the template and making charts available as includable templates to Django (thereby refraining from the costs of a second template engine). My include templates contain the raw nvd3 code taken, e.g. from one of the examples.

I have compiled three gists which assume you have sekizai installed and included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` settings:

1. Python code for the [view function](https://gist.github.com/fsbraun/8840db30b8eafd4eac6f47eb9905b3d2). Remember to include the view function in `urls.py`. The code assumes that the file with the json data is in a static folder.
2. A template called [`base.html`](https://gist.github.com/fsbraun/533a11892fbc8cf28e0263ff563d146d) which does include the html code of the page to be rendered. It has a title and then includes the chart.
3. A [template for the chart](https://gist.github.com/fsbraun/0d89df3c2cff9a5d309f4c5a7157370d) which is a 1:1 copy of the code in the question except that some parameters are dynamically loaded (source file, ticks).

Comment: Thank you Fabian. Your answer is a lot informative and will help everyone understand the Django framework pretty well. But my query was pointing to something else. Still to appreciate your attempt and help to me I will upvote your answer.

Comment: @JafferWilson Thanks for the upvote! Still, it seems I could not help. Can you be more specific on problem? Is it the "real time" part?

Comment: NO I have a file through which I will read it and later I will try to get the real time concept. But first it should show something like what I have in the question.

Comment: OK, I have changed the answer to include three files that actually create exactly your chart by reading the data from a file (served as a static file by django). Maybe this helps a little.

Comment: Thank you for the edit I will try it out. I hope it will help. For your attempts I will accept your answer.